# Learning Python: print variable inside a function from another function

Tags: python

I want to do the following in python:

```
def func1():
 var1 = "something"

def func2():
 print var1
```

What is the correct mode to do this ? I've not found in documentation at all

PS. If possible, it's not my plan to make that 'var1' a global variable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you don't want to pass the variable as a parameter between the function calls. The normal way to share state between functions would be to define a class. It may be overkill for your particular problem, but it lets you have shared state and keep it under control:

```
class C:
    def func1(self):
     self.var1 = "something"

    def func2(self):
     print self.var1

foo = C()
foo.func1()
foo.func2()
```

Comment: Now it worked for me ... i've created a class like you wrote and i can "see" and work with that variable !

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to do things like that. This is because of something called "[scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29)". You can either create a module-level variable or place it in an OOP construct.

Comment: You fail scoping. Lexical scoping forbids this. Dynamic *scoping* is all about this (making caller's locals available to callee).

Answer (score 0):

Well your func2() is trying to print a variable in the scope of another function. You can either

- Return the value of var1 when calling func1 (eg. def func2(): print func1() }
- Call func2 from func1 and pass the value of var1

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
def func1():
   var1 = "something"
   return var1

def func2():
   print func1()
```

If you need func1 to do more things than just define var1, then maybe what you need is to define a class and create objects? See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

filename.py:

---

```
def func1():
     var1 = "something"

def func2():
     var = __ import__('filename').var1
     print var
```